Base class not recoginsed while using wild card generic
Why is the below not working?
A b1 = new B();

Function<? super B, ? extends A> function = x -> new B();

A apply = function.apply(b1);

It gives an error "Required type capture of ? super B, Provided A"
In the above snipper B extends A, then why does it fail? The error happens at .apply(b1).
Please help me understand this..

Bounded wildcards don't mean what you seem to think they mean. See if What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)? and Difference between <? super T> and <? extends T> in Java [duplicate] help.

Generic wildcards are tough to understand. They let you write generic algorithms, but at the cost of what you can assume about the values/parameters/return types. I find it sometimes helps to try to generate different examples of possible legal assignments to the generic wildcard type and they try to see where a usage would conflict with a legal assignment.
Based on your example:
import java.util.function.Function;

class A {
}

class B extends A {
}

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new B();
    B b = new B();

    // Declare a generic wildcard function var that can be
    // assigned any of a set of functions but we (and the
    // compiler don't know which function really.
    Function<? super B, ? extends A> function;

    // Show some functions that can legally be assigned
    switch((int) (Math.random() * 4)) {
      case 0:  function = (A x) -> new A(); break;
      case 1:  function = (A x) -> new B(); break;
      case 2:  function = (B x) -> new A(); break;
      case 3:  function = (B x) -> new B(); break;
      default: function = null; // not possible 
    }

    // Try to use the functions - note that we don't know what
    // actual function was assigned to the generic variable -
    // any attempts to use the function must be allowed by all
    // of the possible assignable functions above.

    A apply1 = function.apply(a);
    // error: incompatible types: A cannot be converted to CAP#1
    // Not allowed because cases 2 and 3 above require a 'B'
    // parameter so the generic wildcard function variable cannot
    // accept an 'A' argument. Doesn't matter if the 'A' arg is
    // actually pointing at a 'B' value or not - compiler must only
    // allow code that works for any assignable value for 'A a'.

    A apply2 = function.apply(b);
    // This is okay - all cases will accept a 'B' argument.
    // 'B' arg can be passed to method with an 'A' parameter.

    B apply3 = function.apply(b);
    // error: incompatible types: CAP#1 cannot be converted to B
    // Arg 'B' is ok, but cannot assign returned result to 'B' var.
    // Not allowed because cases 0 and 1 are functions that return
    // an 'A' return type which cannot be assigned to 'B' var.
  }
}


Side note: You could replace that switch with a switch expression.

@Bert F I almost understood with this example. Thank you lots.
Again,

Does it mean this happens because functions are assignable? So it is a thing with functions alone?
Do we have such surprises for extends also?


"Does it mean this happens because functions are assignable?" - not just functions, any wildcard usage - see http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ305

"Do we have such surprises for extends also?" - yes - see https://stackoverflow.com/q/4343202/11296
